Creality Print does not adjust speed parameters for its own filaments
I'm using Creality Print 5.1.6. If I select a filamente CR-TPU I'm expecting it adjusts the speed parameters according. By the way, CR-TPU is a Creality filament.
Instead, it want to print at maximum speed:

How can I load the correct profile for Creality TPU filament?

The Creality Print filament profiles were set up by Creality themselves, so that is the "correct" profile they provided. I'm not saying it's actually correct, but they provided that profile as the correct one to use. If you want one that prints at lower speeds, you'll probably have to make the changes yourself and save it as a new customized profile. I've had problems with the ones they provide, even for PLA - I was having lots of issues on the Ender 3 KE I just got which I couldn't figure out. I took the same model and sliced it on Orca using their default CR-PLA profile, and it was perfect.

@KenWhite, no, please see my own answer

Such a printing speed is not feasible for TPU, indeed.
But the Creality profile (and even the one in Orca slicer) does not rely on the explicit speeds for this material.
Instead, it uses a specific parameter in the material definition:

Volumetric speed limitation

that is limited to 3 mm³/s for TPU:

While, for example, is 23 mm³/s for PLA.
In fact, after slicing, the actual speeds are correct:


Very nice (and informative). Unfortunately, that wasn't the case for CR PLA. I never did find the difference that was throwing things off so badly; quite frankly, I got so frustrated trying to figure it out that I decided to try another slicer to see if it had the same issues, to rule out a bad roll of filament or a printer defect in my brand-new printer, and an Orca-sliced print turned out absolutely perfectly.
